# Navigation dropdown keeps disappearing when i try hover

Tags: html, css, navigation

Basically I've made a really nice navbar and all, however the dropdown I made isnt working, it shows on hover over my Community tab, but dissappears when i try and hover onto it :(

Does anyone know how i can fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation_items">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">What we do</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a>Community</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Forums</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Check the css code in the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8a92u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the sub menu bit over the main li so it retains the menu on hover.

Add `margin-top:-10px` to sub menu ul and `padding-top: 10px` to get it back to the same UI out look.

```
.navigation_items ul {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/enacUwOf/2/)**

Comment: Hey! Thanks :D now how would i move that dropdown to be underneath the original tab? @Sowmya

Comment: entire horizontal bar or behind the respective menu item?

Comment: I want the new dropdown bars to be underneath the respective menu item, as well as like below eachother and not horizontally (2 tabs are shown horizontally and need them vertically below eachother)

Comment: But how does it make the difference by pushing it back coz menu color is all black so it is not evn visible

Comment: Not pushing it back, like if you see the new dropdown item is a bit to the right of the respective tab above it, i want it directly underneath inline with it

Comment: oh.. add `position:relative` to `.navigation_items li` and `left:0` to `.navigation_items ul`  Check this [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/izufaFE/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
.navigation_items li:hover > ul,
.navigation_items li > ul:hover {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -10px;

}
```

instead of this:

```
.navigation_items li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigation_items ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```